# How to add signal dots on time-series plot for Python Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, graph

I have a dataframe with time-series data on two variables `Reported_Cases` and `Horizontal_Threshold`, here is my graph code:

```
def time_series_graph_horizontal_threshold(df, x_var, y_var):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.grid(True)
    df.plot(x='Year_Week', y=['Reported_Cases', 'Horizontal_Threshold'])
    plt.show()
```

Which generates this graph

[image]

How can I add positive signals on the graph such that when the `Reported_Cases` is higher than the `Horizontal_Threshold`, it will show green signal dots across the graph? We can assume I have another column named `Positive_Signal` which is binary (0, 1=above).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First draw your image, but saving the result (*axes* object):

```
ax = df.plot(x='Year_Week', y=['Reported_Cases', 'Horizontal_Threshold'], grid=True, rot=45)
```

No need to call `plt.grid(True)` separately, maybe you should add parameters
concerning the image size.

Then impose green points on it:

```
ht = df.iloc[0].Horizontal_Threshold
dotY = 280   # Y coordinate of green points
hDist = 2    # Number of weeks between green points
for idx, rc in df.Reported_Cases.items():
    if idx % hDist == 0 and rc > ht:
        ax.plot(idx, dotY, '.g')
```

Writing the above code I assumed that your DataFrame has the index composed of consecutive integers.

Maybe you should set other values of *dotY* and *hDist*. Actually *hDist* depends
on the number of source rows and how is the desired "density" of these points.

For my test data containing 40 rows (weeks) I got:

[image]

Comment: Not sure why I tried your code but the dots don't overlay with the original graph

Comment: The index in your DataFrame should contain consecutive integers, starting from 0. Check this detail. From your third picture I see that the index contains much smaller values, so the original picture has been "compressed" horizontally. The dots have been inserted but much to the right.

Comment: Correction: The index conains rather higher values.